# Siteadvisor treat incapsula as malware

Tags: malware

Siteadvisor (McAfee)  treat incapsula as malware. I have tested a site in different online tools , all the checker prompt that the site is safe except siteadvisor McAfee ..

Siteadvisor shows that " hidden link - http://content.incapsula.com/jsTest.html". But the incapsula link shows "Hello, I am a java script test analytics page"

Someone please help me to get rid of this issue..

Thanks in advance....

Answer (score 0):

I'm Ofer from Imperva Incapsula's Security Team.

Obviously Imperva Incapsula does not distribute malware (we actually block and filter a significant amount of global malware infection attempts).
This is of-course a False Positive in SiteAdvisor, and we will work with them to fix it.

Thank you!
Ofer